# error self python

Tags: python

Estoy tratando de abrir una hoja de excel desde Python y me regresa un error en "self" cuando hago la llamada de la función que esta dentro de una clase.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
import openpyxl

class PI_V1:
    __FAarchivo = "prueba_V1.xlsx"
    __Fhoja = "datosPrueba"

    def abrirArchivo(self):
        workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(self.__FAarchivo)
        sheet = workbook[self.__Fhoja]
        return sheet


test1 = PI_V1 test1.abrirArchivo()
```

Agradecería mucho su ayuda, me imagino que el error ha de ser muy simple, pero créanme que no entiendo.

Comment: ¿qué error te sale exactamente?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Veamos la definición de tu clase:

```
     class PI_V1:
          __FAarchivo = "prueba_V1.xlsx"
          __Fhoja = "datosPrueba"
```

Aquí estás declarando dos variables que tienen alcance de clase y son comunes a todas las instancias de la clase. Para referencialas debes utilizar el nombre de la clase: P1_V1._FArchivo y P1_V1.FHoja. Lo que estás haciendo mal es referenciarlas como si fueran variables de instancia. No puedes hacer self._FArchivo porque esa variable no existe en el ámbito del objeto.

Como veo que son constantes, modifica el self por el nombre de la clase. Si quisieras declarar variables propias de cada instancia lo recomendable es que lo hagas en el método **init**. Ejemplo:

```
        def ___init__(self):
             self._FArchivo = "el valor
```

Answer (score 1):

Tienes dos problemas. El primero es que no instancias la clase.

Tienes la línea:

```
test1 = PI_V1
```

que hace que la variable `test1` sea una referencia *a la clase*, en lugar de serlo a un objeto (instancia) de esa clase. Para que sea un objeto has de llamar al constructor de la clase, con la siguiente sintaxis:

```
test1 = PI_V1()
```

Ahora sí, `test1` sería una referencia a un objeto. La diferencia entre ambos casos es que cuando haces `test1.abrirArchivo()`, en el primer caso se llamaría directamente al método de la clase sin pasarle ningún parámetro (y por eso se queja de que te falta pasarle el `self` como parámetro).

Si en cambio `test1` es un objeto, entonces Python automáticamente le pasa como parámetro el objeto en cuestión. Es decir, que `test1.abrirArchivo()` sería convertido en `PI_V1.abrirArchivo(test1)`, y de este modo en el parámetro `self` recibirás una referencia al objeto sobre el cual actuar.

**Además** de esto, el objeto en cuestión carece de los atributos a los que intentas acceder, pues los has declarado en la clase en lugar de en el objeto. Para que pertenezcan al objeto debes asignarles un valor mediante una sentencia `self.__FAarchivo = valor` por ejemplo. Esta sentencia puede aparecer en cualquier método de la clase, pero lo normal es hacerlo en su constructor.

Por ejemplo podrías tener un constructor que tome como parámetros los valores a asignar, y si quieres puedes darle unos valores por defecto a esos parámetros para poder invocarlo sin tener que pasárselos. Así:

```
class PI_V1:
    def __init__(self, archivo="prueba_V1.xlsx", hoja="datosPrueba"):
        self.__FAarchivo = archivo
        self.__Fhoja = hoja
```

Ahora puedes instanciar el objeto con `test1 = PI_V1()` y entonces el objeto `test1` tendrá los atributos en cuestión, a los que podrás acceder usando `self.atributo` desde cualquiera de sus métodos.

**Un detalle más**. Debido a que has usado nombres de atributo que comienzan por `__`, estos no serán visibles desde fuera del objeto. Es decir, no puedes acceder a `test1.__FAarchivo` ni `test1.__Fhoja`. Sólo puedes acceder a ellos desde un método del objeto usando `self`. Es lo más parecido que python tiene a un atributo *privado*.

En realidad no es tan privado, sólo ocurre que el compilador le ha cambiado el nombre para que sea más difícil de acceder, pero si sabes el nuevo nombre podrías acceder igualmente. En este caso su nuevo nombre sería `test1._PI_V1__FAarchivo`, etc. Esto sólo lo hace con los nombres de atributos o métodos que comiencen por `__`